# Can't define range for get first blank cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have two vba projects, one for employees and another for products.

The first one it is working fine, so I got the code from the employees to use on products.

The thing is that this part of the code works fine in the employees vba project and in products, I receive the 424 Object is Required error:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate

    Dim ID As Long

    With Plan1
    ID = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & ID) = ID - 1
    txtbox1 = Cells(ID, 1)
    End With
```

Can you guys please help me? I tried everything but it seems like an excel bug because I can't figure out what it's going on.

I already thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to ways

either exploit the `Activate` and rely on the currently *Active* sheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate

Dim ID As Long

ID = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1 
Range("A" & ID) = ID - 1
txtbox1 = cells(ID, 1)
```

or you define Plan1 as a Worksheet object and go with it:

```
Dim Plan1 As Worksheet
Set Plan1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1") ' set your worksheet object

Dim ID As Long

With Plan1
    ID = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    .Range("A" & ID) = ID - 1
    txtbox1 = .cells(ID, 1)
End With
```

as to this latter choice, you can go further with the `With ... End With` approach:

```
Dim Plan1 As Worksheet
Set Plan1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1") ' set your worksheet object

With Plan1 ' reference your sheet
    With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) ' reference its column A first empty cell after last not empty one
        .Value = .row - 1 ' set referenced cell value as its row index minus one
        txtbox1 = .Value ' set some 'txtbox' object default property to referenced cell value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help.

I've tried the first one and I got the Invalid Reference error. The second one was working but I don't understand why sometimes the textbox was filled with the result and sometimes don't. 

So I went to the third option and it worked. The textbox it's getting filled xD

I just can't understand why in my employees project my code it's working fine and in this one don't.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. The three codes are equivalent and the second was missing a dot before the “cells” reference (I edited and added it).

Comment: `Plan1` could be the codename for the sheet - if in your `VBAProject` explorer your sheet is called `Plan1 (Plan1)` you can go with your original of just using `With Plan1`, if on the other hand it says similar to  `Sheet1 (Plan1)` then you need to define it.  Also... you didn't just say _exploit the Activate and rely on the currently Active sheet_ did you?! :P

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Dim ID As Long

with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")
    ID = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    .Range("A" & ID) = ID - 1
     txtbox1 = .Cells(ID, 1)
End With
```

Inside a With ... End With block, .Range and .Cells become thisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Range(...) and thisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Cells(...). That doesn't mean you can just arbitrarily use Plan1 as a worksheet object.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I tried and the txtbox was not getting filled by the result :(

But thank you for the hint xD I managed with the last option of the another answer.